# How do weapon stats and leveling work?

Tags: secret-of-mana

I have some questions about the weapon leveling system in SoM, which isn't super clear to me:

1. Each character has his own individual weapon progression chart, but **is there any easy way to switch from one character's weapons stats view to another's** ?  It works with the general stats view by pressing <kbd>Start</kbd>, but it doesn't seem to work for the others' views...
2. In the weapons stats view, each weapon is preceded by two numbers separated by a colon; the first number is the weapon's level (for the selected character), the second seems to be a percentage accomplished to reach the next level (if any).

   1. **How does this percentage increase?**  Do you have to actually hit or kill monsters with the weapon in order to raise its level ?  Or will having it equipped while mobs are getting killed (possibly by another character) be enough ?
   2. **How is the amount of XP earned by each weapon calculated?**  Is it always the same whatever you are doing with the weapon, or is it a fixed amount gained by all the characters every time a monster gets killed ?

Comment: I've removed the snes tag, as we generally only apply console tags to questions that are *specifically* about the console itself.

Comment: Yep, it didn't seem revelant to me neither.

Comment: My apologies - I added the console tag because of the reference to the 'Start' button, something that's specific to the SNES version of the game (instead of, say, the iOS version).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As far as I remember there isn't a way to cycle through characters on the experience screen, as the buttons that would normally let you do that (L/R) are used to switch between the Magic and Weapon screens for the magic users.
2. Weapon experience is calculated as follows:

   - Killing an enemy will give **(9 - weapon level) experience points** to whoever dealt the last blow (the killer). 100 points will bring the weapon to its next level, with the maximum being based on how many orbs you've gotten for that weapon.
   - If the killer's level is two or more higher than the enemy they killed, they receive half the experience points, rounded down.
   - Everyone else in your party will receive half the experience they would have gotten for the same kill for their current weapon, rounded down.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer !  But when you say "9 - weapon level", I'm not sure what you're talking about.  Could you develop ?

Comment: The number of points you receive will go down as your weapon level increases. At the initial level, 0, you can get 9 points for each kill, but if your weapon is at level 5 you'll only get 4 points. The maximum for any weapon is level 9.

Comment: Haaa ok !  So that's how they make the leveling of higher levels more difficult :)  thanks !

Comment: Adding onto this, you can (as far as I am aware) cut grass and rocks early on in order to gain some exp towards a weapon level up. I've tested this on the SNES back as a kid when I played this game constantly, it does work.